# heroku dialgoflow error showing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error

Tags: node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es, chatbot

i am creating chat bot and trying to deploy it on heroku but it showing error i don't know why i tried all possibilities but didn't work if anyone know please help me out

```
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061544+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:22) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061551+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061552+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061552+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061553+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061554+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061554+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
2022-05-28T07:58:09.061605+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:22) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 
9)
```